# How to exclude a specific URL from basic authentication in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, mod-proxy, http-basic-authentication

Two scenarios:

**Directory**

I want my entire server to be password-protected, so I included this directory config in my `sites-enabled/000-default`:

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user someuser
</Directory>
```

The question is how can I exclude a specific URL from this?

**Proxy**

I found that the above password protection doesn't apply to mod_proxy, so I added this to my `proxy.conf`:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwords
  Require user someuser
</Proxy>
```

How do I exclude a specific proxied URL from the password protection? I tried adding a new segment:

```
<Proxy http://myspecific.url/>
  AuthType None
</Proxy>
```

but that didn't quite do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Satisfy Any` to exclude something from `AuthType` requirements.

If you can be more specific about what the URL is to be excluded and how your site is configured now, then I can be more specific about how this should be applied.

Comment: I thought my description above was rather detailed ... what is missing? The specific URL I'm trying to exclude from basic auth is http://mysite.com/status. Truth be told, this question might not be so relevant to me now, because of this: http://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters