# How to add http host header in URL?

Tags: https, http, url, host, headers

I have web app deployed in K8 in aws & configured LoadBalancer to call the same from internet.
In the Postman I call like ,

GET https://myteams.myorg.net/config
Headers: Host doom.myteams.myorg.net
I can convert as corresponding http request as below

GET /config HTTP/1.1
Host: myteams.myorg.net
Host: doom.myteams.myorg.net

But I want to call the same from browser URL ? I tried several ways but can't successfully include  a http header in the URL
tried  - https://myteams.myorg.net/config/doom.myteams.myorg.net  but the "/config/doom.myteams.myorg.net" is being treated as params.

Comment: I cannot find any converter which converts curl or http request to URL which can be executed in browsers like chrome

Comment: To get the first request the URL might be http://doom.myteams.myorg.net/https://myteams.myorg.net/config The Host should come from the URL and the GET /xxxx is the path of the url, we can see that the Get part is weird, I would say a broken client generated that request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a subdomain `doom.myteams.example.net` to your DNS, which points to the IP address of your server.

After that, opening `https://doom.myteams.example.net` will get your request to the correct virtual host.

If you want this to be available for one computer only, you can edit `/etc/hosts` (*nix) or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (Windows) and add the hostname + ip address in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You can't set HTTP headers as part of URL, it's not the way it works.

At best you may be able to use a browser plugin to add/set arbitrary HTTP headers, but that will depend on the browser you are using. And will be a one off test/development option.

The `Host` variable needs to match the host portion of the URL, this is how the Ingress controller knows which service to route the request to.

Comment: I was thining some thing like this should be possible-https://serverfault.com/questions/371907/can-you-pass-user-pass-for-http-basic-authentication-in-url-parameters/471667#471667.  I need this in URL format to pass as a target to blackbox-exporter

Comment: Yeah, except this is NOT A HOST HEADER. it is basic authentication parameters encoded in the URL - and a target that expects this. What you mean would add a parameter to EVERY URL (making them unique) AND would have to be supported by the load balancer - totally different game.